# Recently joined user can edit any question / change the complete question or answer

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I have referred already asked questions regarding this, but my question is a **different** one.

A user who recently joined stackoverflow with reputation **1** edited the answer given by me and which was quite useful to the needy people as it got **25** likes till date. Making/suggesting few changes is always acceptable, but in this case he changed the complete answer/reply.

Thanks to review feature of stackoverflow otherwise I might have lost a really good answer.

So - my question is : are we really allowing each and every user to edit the question or answer like anything ?

This scenario need to be thought of.

Attaching screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: The suggested edit can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8376661

Answer (score 13):

Why are you concerned? The suggested edit was rejected.

Suggestions like that can be made by anyone who is not review banned - even anonymous (not logged in, or not a member) users. However all suggestions go through the review queue, where members with at least 2000 rep judge whether the edit is satisfactory. Generally the system works pretty well. When an edit is suggested the author of the post gets notified, and the author has immediate rejection rights, so if you had been present when the suggestion was active you could have personally rejected it.

You might also recollect if you did [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read it carefully (which we hope you did) there are several mentions about editing - the site is maintained collectively. It's one of the things you agree to when you become a member.

Comment: I agree with you, but I have one doubt. You said that you can immediately reject the change/edit. If I am not available right now, then will it wait until I approve or reject the edit ?

Comment: No, it will sit in the queue till either the right number of people have reviewed it or the author has rejected or accepted it. If you're not around then you just have to trust the people who review it. In any case there is a rollback mechanism as mentioned by Robert.

Answer (score 3):

If you disagree with the edit, roll it back.

Users with less than 2000 rep have their edits reviewed by users with more than 2000 rep, so several of them must have approved the edit for the edit to actually take place. That doesn't always achieve the desired result, hence the rollback function.

Basically we trust reviewers to reject this kind of wholesale change, which is why we have a reject reason of "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post..."

In your case the edit was rejected, so the system worked as designed. Nothing happened to your answer i.e. if a tree falls in the forest and nobody hears it, does it make a noise?

Comment: So is it the case that the owner (of question / answer) have rights to roll back the edit immaterial of anyone of the reviewers have already approved it ?

Comment: Depends on the circumstances, but mostly yes. If you put swear words in the post and an edit removes them then you rollback the edit to put the swear words back in you may find yourself in trouble but on the whole providing you're acting sensibly you'll be fine.